# A French calendar from an English calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

The code bellow is about an English calendar:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var calendar = $('#notice_calendar');

        $('#notice_calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },

            //defaultView: 'basicWeek',

            editable: false,
            firstDay: 1,
            height: 530,
            droppable: false,


        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to change this code to have a French calendar.
[French calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwV8G.png)

Comment: You need to mention what library you are using to provide the function `fullCalendar()`

Comment: PHP tag because i'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: @Flint I'm using fullcalendar js library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/), you can use the option `lang: 'fr'`:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#notice_calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },

        //defaultView: 'basicWeek',

        editable: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        height: 530,
        droppable: false,
        lang: 'fr'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I downloaded full calendar-2.9.1 and I followed your instructions but nothing appears

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined   fullcalendar.js:15

Comment: @NounouBiatrice include this link before full calendar include `http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js`

Comment: I found this solution into another discussion. I tried it now:                     <script src='/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>                             The calendar is displayed but the display is weird. Can I put a screen printed that you can see the display?

Comment: @NounouBiatrice ok put in your question please

Comment: I added <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' /> and It's okay. Thanks.                                                                                                The link that helped me:                                                                                  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/